# center of mass 2d with matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I got different datasets, now I wanted to calculate the center of mass the different datasets. (the datasets include always x and y values)

```
close all, clc
load('dataset1.mat');
plot(x,y, '-'), hold on
load('dataset2.mat');
plot(x,y, '-'), hold on
load('dataset3.mat');
plot(x,y, '-'), hold on
```

So I can interpolerate those datasets by just using a "-" inside my plot function but I have no idea how to write a center of mass code, my programming skills in Matlab are quite bad since I programmed for years only with c+, I also tried to find a proper decent code to calculate a center of mass of a 2D-dataset but I just found a thread about a 3D-array....

Comment: See [Centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) in Wikipedia, section "Of a finite set of points".  You should `plot(mean(x),mean(y))`

Comment: yeah and can I see the coordinates exactly because I dont wanna only to plot it?

Comment: Coordinate x: `mean(x)`.  Do the same for y.  It is not too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the center of mass of a particle system, where all particles have the same mass:

`plot(mean(x),mean(y),'or')`

Comment: i get the following error: `Error using plot
Invalid first data argument

Error in project2 (line 9)
plot(mean(x),mean(y),'o','r'), hold on`

Comment: fixed? too long not using matlab :)

Comment: that works now, but I get only 1 center of mass I should get 3 according to my 3 datasets, since I want to compare like how far they are from each other, so I also need to get from the plotting to a kind of number of percentage, so far thanks for the help that worked pretty fine and thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: Each `load()` call overwrites `x` and `y` variables. Repeat the `plot()` call for the centroid the same way you're repeating the other plot calls

Comment: thanks I'll try that later since I have to go to work in 3 hours